# Travis CI support for XCode 6.3

Tags: travis-ci

When will Travis support XCode 6.3?
It was announced on April 9 that it would be up soon.
http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-04-09-this-week-in-travis-ci/

Comment: A month later, nothing changed on Travis side

Answer (score 3):

As of May 26th, there is beta support for Xcode 6.3 in Travis: http://blog.travis-ci.com/2015-05-26-xcode-63-beta-general-availability/

You just have to add `osx_image: beta-xcode6.3` in your `.travis.yml` file to opt in.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.travis-ci.com/

Update on 4-20-15: Not ready yet. Travis CI will need a few more weeks. Their new infrastructure requires OS X Yosemite (10.10), which does not support it yet.

> There is a bit of unknown here, because Xcode 6.3 requires OS X 10.10 (a.k.a. Yosemite). The new infrastructure service provider is running on a version of virtualization software that does not officially support 10.10.